# change server date postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a postgresql db (v9.4) and its default year is 2026.
Is there any way I can modify it?
I have read about modifying the `postgresql.conf` file, but I have just found the `timezone` property.

Comment: what's the server date?

Comment: How do you know the "default  year" is 2026? What is the SQL statement you are using?

Comment: when I execute "select now();" I get "2026-01-10 07:26:14.141161+01"

Comment: I'd guess the only sane fix to it would be to set the OS time properly.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the database have any way of changing the current date. Its date is the computer date. You should probably check the date at operating system level and, possibly, correct it.

Comment: many thanks for the hint. It actually was that.

Comment: Not true. [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443155/911419) the correct answer.